# Checkout keeps redirecting to shoppingcart

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, redirect, shopping-cart

Using Magento 1.9.1. 
After reaching the final step in Checkout, it loops/redirects back to the shopping cart.
The articles in the shopping cart are not removed.
I have been searching for days, and tried every possible solution I could find, like:

1) Increased Cookie Lifetime

2) Redirect to CMS-page if cookies are disabled = No

3) web/url/redirect_to_base to 0 instead of 1

4) Clear var/cache and var/sessions folders

5) Disabled and changed shipping and payment methods

and so on...

I hope someone can help.

Comment: would you be able to check whether there is any error logged in either var/log/system.log or var/log/exception.log?

Answer (score 1):

Since I know nothing at all about your system, I have to shoot from the hip: is it possible that your checkout form lacks form_key hidden element?

Comment: This is in my cart.phtml:
       <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

Is that what you mean?

Comment: This is cart template, not checkout template. Besides it sounds like your cart works just fine.

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me where to look?

Comment: Well, it depends on theme and what kind of checkout you use. Standard template has it here:

`template/onepage/review/info.phtml`

Also, as I mention I know next to nothing what you did and what caused this issue.

Comment: I know, but I appreciate your thoughts.
THis is in app/design/frontend/base/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml:
    //<![CDATA[
        review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
    //]]>

I use "ReducedCheckout" but when I disable this extension it also redirects back.

Comment: did you checkout what is going on in var/log folder? If it fails because of error, there should be something either in system.log or exception.log ...

Comment: Yes, I have been checking those log files. I only had errors in a dhl file but when I disabled that shipping method, no more errors. Just checked again.

Comment: Well, at this point I'm out of ideas. Still, lets backtrack -- are we talking about new installation and default theme?

Comment: I use the Queldorei Shopper theme, url is testshop.etkserver.nl.
Still in testing phase, have not really paid a lot of attention to the final steps of checkout, as I had very complex discount rules that needed to be implemented first.

Comment: If you switch off Shopper and try default theme, does it still redirect you back to the shopping cart page?

Comment: I changed the template to the default Magento one, and the problem persists... still the looping checkout...

Comment: Roll back your discount rules changes just to try it if it helps with the checkout not working. Don't forget about clearing cache/reindex - then try.

Comment: Also do you have a list of third party extensions installed?

Comment: I disabled the extension I use for discounts, and no change. I still had a version on a shared hosting server and I tried there with the extensions I am using right now, and no problem there. Checkout works fine there.

Comment: Umm .. are you sure you have all necessary PHP extensions installed? Such as mcrypt? Same codebase, different results indicates that the problem might be on system level.

Comment: phpinfo generates: MCRYPT enabled. version 2.5.8
Is that what you mean? And I agree but totally clueless now on where to look to solve it.

Comment: No suggestion anymore? Something I could try or look at?

Comment: As an older testsite works, I compared the button "Proceed to Checkout" (final step) with Firebug, HTML is:
---
The OLD (checkout working) site: 
<button type="submit" title="Plaats bestelling" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="review.save();"><span><span>Plaats bestelling</span></span></button>
---
The NEW (checkout not working) site:
<button type="button" title="Proceed to Checkout" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout" onclick="window.location='http://testshop.etkserver.nl/checkout/onepage/';"><span><span>Proceed to Checkout</span></span></button>
---
Could that b the problem?

Comment: Both sites have same PHP version?

Comment: New site has 5.4.38, old site has 5.4.40 (builddate May 10, and it worked before May 10 as well )
Anyway, now I cannot reach the final step and get redirected back to the cart after the first step. This happened before, don't know why I could get to the final step, I don't think I changed anything.
Grrrhhh... have been searching for a solution for so long, appreciate your help, but no idea where to look anymore. Shipping and billing methods are also the same on both sites. I lack knowledge and have to "trial and error" debug.

Comment: Still searching… and keep comparing the two sites and I see a difference with InspectElement on the final button “place order” :

**Network->Headers->Jquery.noconflict.js**
The new (NOT working one) gives 'Status Code: 200 OK (from cache)'

The old (working) one gives: 'Status Code: 304 Not Modified'

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

My hosting provider changed my php.ini settings without consulting me at all. The `memory_limit` setting got changed to default (`32M`, 32 megabytes I think).

```
memory_limit=32M
```

I changed it to `4G` (4 gigabytes) and the problem went away.

```
memory_limit=4G
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error that is happening on the final step: some exception is occurring in the order placement.

#### Try to intercept the error as it happens:

Use Chrome Developer tools, select the source tab and open `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js` (replace `base/default` with the package and theme that you are currently using). Set a breakpoint on this line (line 65 for the latest version of Magento):

```
ajaxFailure: function(){
    location.href = this.failureUrl; // <<< This line
},
```

When the debugger breaks at this line, click into the Network tab. See what error details there are listed (if any) in the latest request.

#### Find the error in server/Magento logs:

Next, review the server logs to see if an error is being logged there. This may be in `/var/log/httpd/[log-file-name].log`. Do a `tail -f [log-file-name].log` to watch the error logs come in.

You can also look in your Magento's `var/log/exception.log` file to see if there are errors being logged there.

Either one should get you to the problem.